# Transforming a vertex moves other vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices

Hi I'm new to blender and am trying to model a character. In the tutorial I'm following each vertex moves independently. For example, when moving one vertex only that vertex moves, whereas for me it's moving the other vertices, which is making it harder for me to build a basic model the way it should be.

This is how it works in the tutorial:
[image]

And this is what it's doing for me:
[image]

Rather than distorting the area it's moving the whole section. I've searched with all the possible questions I can think of but can't find anything, which solves this problem. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is proportional editing turned on?

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUUUUU! That solved my problem. The "o" key turns it on or off. I shall now enjoy building characters. Thank you again!